# MVC C# ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open. error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have added this to my MVC RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "categories",
url: "{sub}",
defaults: new { controller = "cat", action = "Index" }
, constraints: new { sub = new MyCatConstraint() }
);
```

and this is my MyCatConstraint Class:

```
 public class MyCatConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {



        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
             KhanoumiDbContext db = new KhanoumiDbContext();



            if (values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
            {
                string thisCat = values["sub"].ToString();

                    return db.tbl_Category.Any(c => c.Cat_Name_En == thisCat);


            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

After add these sometimes I get this error :

**ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.**

would you please tell me what should I do to solve this issue  ?

Comment: You should cache the content of `tbl_Category` so you don't need a database call for each route that is checked.

Comment: Cache it where? How? Also, it should be live, category could change any moment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF Core - System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697965/ef-core-system-invalidoperationexception-executereader-requires-an-open-and-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `KhanoumiDbContext db = new KhanoumiDbContext()` in`using` statement.

Comment: the problem was in another controller and I used `using` in that and my problem solved.